# Refactoring mocks in RSpec controller specs

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, mocking

I have a `TopicsController`, with `new` action:

```
def new
  @section = Section.find(params[:section_id])
  @topic = @section.topics.build
end
```

While trying to test this simple behavior, I ended up with quite ugly and robust mock structure

```
describe "#new" do
  it "builds a topic with a given section" do
    new_topic = mock_model(Topic)
    topics = mock('topics')
    topics.should_receive(:build).and_return(new_topic)

    section = mock_model(Section)
    section.should_receive(:topics).and_return(topics)

    Section.should_receive(:find).with("1").and_return(section)
    get :new, :section_id => 1

    assigns[:topic].should == new_topic
  end
end
```

I'd like to make this code simpler, but I don't see how. I can't get rid of the `@section` mock, and it has to return something specific on the chained `.topics.build` call to allow me to set an expectation.

**Is there any simpler way to do this?** I'm using RSpec 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
describe TopicsController do
  specify :new do
    section = stub_chain(:topics, :build).and_return(:new_topic)
    Section.should_receive(:find).with(1).and_return(section)

    get :new, section_id: 1

    assigns_should_match section: section, topic: :new_topic
  end
end

def assigns_should_match(h)
  h.each { |k,v| assigns[k].should == v }
end
```

Answer (score -4):

Controller specs are needlessly painful, as you're finding out. Instead of this, write a Cucumber scenario (with real objects, not mocks).

Comment: Cucumber is not a solution to this question. Cucumber is for acceptance tests (or integration tests if that's what you really want to use it for) and should not be used to testing the controller. You will end up with slower and less maintainable tests using cucumber for the wrong things.

Comment: @odin Integration tests (i.e. Cucumber stories) are actually the only viable way to test the controller in most cases (the exception *might* be for controllers that are API endpoints). Generally speaking, Rails controllers don't need unit tests (only models and similar objects do); in fact, controller unit tests tend to test the wrong things, and therefore they'll make you think your application is well tested when it isn't. So yes...Cucumber *is* the proper solution here.